# appmaker Cloud SQL works in preview but not when published with same user

Tags: google-app-maker

My first real app, clearly missing something. Everything works in preview but when I publish > replace existing deployment > open app when done, the published app loads and like a button click to another page works but no data loads on any page. I'm in as the same user so am at a loss for what to try next. Thanks in advance for any help.

Update: Set the Security on the SQL Data Models to Everyone. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: The SQL data tables were empty. The first Publish of a new Deployment creates new empty copy of the database.